# Add a Quick Add Event to a Google Calendar from inside a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-calendar-api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've looked all over but I can't figure out how to add a quick calendar event to google calendar from inside a google spreadsheet. Google provides code (Javascript) to send an email from inside a google spreadsheet, but in addition to sending an email I want to be able to send a quick cal event. Here is the Javascript I'm starting out with and I copied and pasted the last line which was a code I found about calendar quick add. This is my first time coding or using javascript.

```
    function sendEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
      // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
        var message = row[1];       // Second column
        var subject = "CRM Update";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventFromDescription();
      }
    }
```

I also found this code, but it might be a diff language?

```
    function createQuickAddEvent ($client, $quickAddText) {
      $gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
      $event = $gdataCal->newEventEntry();
      $event->content = $gdataCal->newContent($quickAddText);
      $event->quickAdd = $gdataCal->newQuickAdd('true');
      $newEvent = $gdataCal->insertEvent($event);
    }
```

Any advice would be useful, or directing me to a page that might have this code I'm looking for.
Thanks for your time.
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You should use GAS (Google Apps Script - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), which you can embed inside your spreadsheet. It is similar to JavaScript with additions. The first example above is GAS (the second is php which is one of the languages that have client libraries to Google API - https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries)

The script can be attached to a menu item that you can add to the spreadsheet or as a trigger to changes in the spreadsheet and even building a dedicated UI for event adding.

Check out the documentation for adding calendar event with GAS at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_calendar#createEvent